# MDX: pairs of measures on columns

Tags: mdx

I have the following measures:
[Measures].[ValueA], [Measures].[ValuesAdiff], [Measures].[ValueB], [Measures].[ValuesBdiff]..

I want to display pairs of appropriate measures so it looks smth like:

```
                          ----------------------------
                         |    Value1   | Value2      |
 -----------------------------------------------------
| ValueA  | ValueAdiff   |    10       | 1           |
 -----------------------------------------------------
| ValueB  | ValueBdiff   |    13       | 3           |
 -----------------------------------------------------
...
```

Basically just display bunch of measures in pairs next to each other

Comment: What is ValueAdiff and ValueBdiff?

Comment: two measures, and in this example for the first row Value1 is value of measure ValueA, Value2 is value of measures ValueAdiff, for the second row they point to ValueB and ValueBdiff

Comment: @AntonPolyakov this isn't possible if they are all part of the Measures dimension - are they really Measures or actually calculated members that could be moved to a different host dimension?

Comment: they are measures. So it's not possible?

Comment: No. If you want to do this my guess is that your Cube is not properly designed for your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO the conclusion is - it is not possible with MDX if these are two different measures and it is a sign that data model is not appropriate.

What I've done - I implemented diff values as MDX subquery computing it from original value instead of having another measure